# Beginner Question: Assigning an indexed Variable to a given list

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, index

I am pretty new to the game and have a problem, which i am sitting on for hours.

1) I created a random Matrix 5x5

```
Q=Table[Q[i,j]=RandomReal[{0.6,1}],{i,5},{j, 5}]
```

2) I want to have the sums over the columns for i=1,...,5

```
Total[Q,{2}]
```

3) This gives me a list of the sums `{{Value1,...,Value5}}`

4) Now i want to assign a Variable p with index i, p[i], to the Value i.
That means p[1]=Value1 etc.

My approach was to manipulate the list first and generate single tuples to get `{{Value1},{...},{Value5}}`

```
p[i]= Tuples[Total[Q,{2}],1]
```

And now i am missing the essential step to really get for p[i] = Value [i]

With the command `Extract[p,1]` I get the Value1. However, i just need to type in p[1] to get the corresponding Value1. I tried to get there with a Table command, however, it didn't work out as expected. Since it works for a normal List as for instance:

```
Table[x[i]=RandomReal[0.6,1],{i,5}]
```

Where x[2]=Value2 etc.

Thank you for your help and advice in advance.
Greetings,

Pascal

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: If you say `p = Total[Q, {2}]` then you can easily access the individual values using `p[[2]]` or `p[[3]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a rather dangerous monster.

Observe what happens:

```
Q=Table[Q[i,j]=RandomReal[{0.6,1}],{i,5},{j, 5}]
```

First of all, Mathematica evaluates the right hand side which is the `Table[...]` part. For every value of the iterators it then *evaluates the expression `Q[i,j]=RandomReal[...]`* which returns you the `RandomReal` part (a number). Under the cover it also performs the assignment. The symbol `Q` is now sort of a function* (not a matrix) that takes two arguments and is defined for values of the arguments `i=1..5; j=1..5`.

*Disclaimer: I say "sort of a function" here and it's the easy way to wrap your head around it for now, but actually a real function in Mathematica is a slightly different type of construct*

But as soon as processing the right hand side of the assignment operator is complete, Mathematica assigns the output of the `Table` function (which is just a matrix) to Q. So we loose the definitions for `Q[i,j]` as every call to `Q` is now actually instantly replaced by something else.

Try `Q[1,1]` and see the output:

> `{{... 5x5 list ...}}[1,1]`. (and not the upper-left element of the matrix).

In Mathematica you do not need to assign each element of an array individually. It is absolutely fine (and the right way, in fact) to assign a 5x5 matrix to one symbol. Like so:

```
Q=Table[RandomReal[{0.6,1}],{i,5},{j, 5}]
```

Then you can get the third row like so:

```
Q[[3]]
```

> `{... list of 5 elements ...}`

and, say the 4th element of the 2nd row like so:

```
Q[[2,4]]
```

> `* a number *`

Then, as described in the comments:

```
p = Tuples[Q,{2}]
```

and access each individual element of `p` (which is a list) with double square brackets: `p[[1]], p[[2]], ...`

Comment: You're welcome. Take delight at the joys of the Mathematica paradigm, where everything can be an "object" and iterative constructs are rarely needed. Also, bonus: `RandomReal[{0.6,1}, {5,5}]` - no `Table` necessary.

Comment: Okay, now again. Accidentally hit Enter. Thank you again for your comment. I hope the monster is tamed. I try to work with that. Merci

Comment: Yeah, also you might want to restart the session before trying with the suggested code (some bugs might crop up if Q is still assigned to "the monster")